# Different in VBA and VB.NET for ADO Object

Tags: c#, vb.net, vba, excel

I have a un-explain problem when work with VBA and VB.NET. I start a project in VBA with a necessary of access data. I used ADO (Active Data Object 6.1), everything work fine with this example code:

```
Option Explicit
Private uConnect As ADODB.Connection
Private uCommand As ADODB.Command
Private uRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
Public Sub openConnection()
On Error GoTo ERRHANDLE:
Dim sConnection As String

sConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "database.xlsx;" & _
                    "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

        'declare

Set uConnect = New ADODB.Connection       'give memory

uConnect.ConnectionString = sConnection
uConnect.Open

ERRHANDLE:
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error"
End If

End Sub
```

When I start another project with VB.NET with same situation. First I try COM reference to ADO ( active data object 6.1 ) or using assembly reference ADODB both not work with error "Provider not found", code:

```
Public Class Input
    Private Const connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
                                            "Data Source=" & sSource & ";" &
                                            "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;"

    Private Sub btnGetData_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGetData.Click
        Dim cn As New Connection
        Dim da As New Recordset            
        Dim sSQL As String

        Try
            My.Computer.Audio.PlaySystemSound(SystemSounds.Exclamation)
            da = New Recordset
            cn = New Connection
            cn.ConnectionString = connstring
            cn.Open()

            MessageBox.Show(cn.State.ToString)
            cn.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Database Input Error")

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

My system win 10. 64 bit. office 64 bit.

I found in internet the solution is to install, Access Database Engine. Problem solve for the second case. But why there is this difference in VBA and VB.NET, why VBA do not need to install more engine to run.

Comment: what if you change the project to run as `x86` or `AnyCpu` I would try changing the project properties to `.x86` also make sure that you are not getting the reference from the GAC vs what you have in your project reference, also look at changing the `CopyLocal=` property for that Dll to `True`

Comment: Why would you use the COM ADODB library instead of just using a managed provider like `System.Data.Odbc`?

Comment: @MethodMan : I try both x86 and x64 will not work until I install of Access Database engine [link](http://www.connectionstrings.com/the-microsoft-ace-oledb-12-0-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine/)

Comment: @Comintern : I used to familiar with COM ADODB library so I start with this. Even I use ODBC, I change the connection string and the error will be "driver is not found"

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer, but it looks like youre trying to move from vba to vb.net with database connections. Here is waht I use in a couple of different vb.net projects. Hopefully itll help you transition smoothly.

I learned the hard way that not everything in vba directly translates into vb

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

    Dim provider As String
    Dim dataFile As String
    Dim connString As String

    Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ="
    dataFile = "pathto.accdb"
    connString = provider & dataFile
    myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
    End Sub

    Private Sub NextSub()

        str = "sql statement;"
        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While dr.Read()

           'do stuff with teh reader

        End While

        myConnection.Close()
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however it is not work for my case. Same error which I mention.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting in an old post!

I solve the same problem by install database engine provided in this link

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-quotthe-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local?forum=vstsdb

Worked on my win10 64bit machine.

Hope this help anyone have the same problem.